# Excel: Display the value in the cell following a specific term

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an extremely disorganized and very long excel spreadsheet. All data are in a single column, mostly filled with irrelevant values. However, every 300 lines or so, there's a keyword which tells me that the next cell down will contain a value that I want to see. The keyword does not appear in a predictable way, so I can't simply say "give me every 301st line". I need to write some kind of lookup statement that says "whenever the term 'foo' appears in a cell, display the contents of the next cell down from 'foo'."

Here's example data:

[image]

The result that I'm after would look like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: I have absolutely no idea why this was marked as "too broad" since I provided a very specific problem with example data, and I was immediately provided with two great answers to my problem.

For any future users who may come across this problem, see the solution presented by BigBen in the comments below - it worked perfectly. The answer chosen as correct will also work, but involves invoking a VB script.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or something that will need to be updated?

Comment: One-time thing.

Comment: Assuming the data is in column A, in B2 put `=A1="Foo"` and drag down. Then filter on column B for TRUE. Copy/paste visible cells in new column.

Comment: Damn this is great, very neat macro that I didn't know about. Thanks! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search column A for any key in the dictionary and add a row to column B containing the row after the matching term in column A. The columns it searches can be changed relatively easily

```
Sub CopyAfterMatch()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'add more values here
    dict.Add "foo", ""

    Dim i As Long
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim count As Long

    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each key In dict.keys
            If InStr(Range("A" & i).Value2, key) > 0 Then
                count = count + 1
                Range("B" & count).Value2 = Range("A" & i + 1).Value2
            End If
        Next key
    Next i

End Sub
```

To add more words that you want to check for, just add another line like so:
`dict.Add "newKey", ""`

Comment: This is great, thanks!